# puppet-acl module on Windows throws transactionstore.yaml corrupt error

Tags: puppet

Trying out puppet-acl module on Windows Server 2016, Preview5. I'm getting the weirdest error on the **second puppet run**. If i remove the trnsactionstore.yaml file, and re-run the puppet agent, the behavior is repeatable. Im running puppet4 with latest agent version.

This is my codeblock

```
acl { "c:/temp":
  permissions => [
    { identity  =>  'Administrator', rights => ['full'] },
    { identity  =>  'Users', rights => ['read','execute'] }
  ],
}
```

This is the output from the puppet-run.

```
PS C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\puppet\cache\state> puppet agent -t
Info: Using configured environment 'local'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for opslowebf02n02.local
Error: Transaction store file C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/cache/state/transactionstore.yaml is corrupt (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)); replacing
Error: Transaction state file C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/cache/state/transactionstore.yaml is valid YAML but not returning a hash. Check the file for corruption, or remove it before continuing.
Info: Applying configuration version '1471436916'
Notice: /Stage[main]/platform_base_system::Role::Windows/Exec[check-powershell-exection-policy]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/configs_iis::Profile::Default/Exec[check-iis-global-anonymous-authentication]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: Applied catalog in 7.42 seconds
```

In the transactionstore.yaml file, this is the error section:

```
Acl[c:/temp]:
   parameters:
     permissions:
       system_value:
       - !ruby/hash:Puppet::Type::Acl::Ace {}
       - !ruby/hash:Puppet::Type::Acl::Ace {}
     inherit_parent_permissions:
       system_value: :true
```

Comment: Just spottet, that the puppet-agent is newer of the OS that fails... tested this against Server 2012R2

Working, Server 2012 R2  Debug: Runtime environment: puppet_version=4.5.3, ruby_version=2.1.9, run_mode=agent, default_encoding=IBM437


Not working, Server 2016 TP5  Debug: Runtime environment: puppet_version=4.6.0, ruby_version=2.1.9, run_mode=agent, default_encoding=IBM437

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved by dowwngrading the puppet agent to 4.5.3.
Behavior of the 4.6.0 version must have changed.

With 4.5.3 i still see the error in the logfile, but the puppetrun does not fail
I'll try to talk to the people at puppet about this.

```
Acl[c:/temp]:
parameters:
  permissions:
  system_value:
  - !ruby/hash:Puppet::Type::Acl::Ace {}
  - !ruby/hash:Puppet::Type::Acl::Ace {}
  inherit_parent_permissions:
  system_value: :true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is being tracked as https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-6629. It's almost coincidental that you created https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-6630 right afterwards.

Comment: true.. my duplicate ticket was closed pretty fast :)